# Set null as return value in selectize.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, selectize.js

Can anyone tell how to set null as return value in selectize.js if the selector is empty. When i went through the library, i got to know it returns an empty sting if value is empty. How to edit this? Thanks in advance